# Select from two select queries is returning nxn rows in final result SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have two select queries and what I want to achieve is select from these two queries using join and perform some SQL side calculation in final selected query. The problem I am facing is that final query is returning nxn rows(i.e. first query is returning 5 rows, second also returning  rows, but the select of these select returning 5x5 =25 rows), I tried everything but no success. Though individually these queries are working perfect.

```
@testid int
as
begin
(select t1.sid,t1.sectionid,t1.sectionName,t1.nmark,t1.pmark,t2.correctAns,t2.wrongAns,t2.sectiontotal,(t1.nmark*t2.wrongAns) as nmarktotal,(t1.pmark*t2.correctAns) as pmarktotal,(t1.pmark*t2.correctAns-t1.nmark*t2.wrongAns) as sectiontotalmark 
    from
        (select m.sid,m.sectionid,(select sectionName from oe_batch_section where sectionid=m.sectionid ) as sectionname,m.sectionNmark as nmark,m.sectionPmark as pmark from oe_exam_main_pre_section_map m where sid in (select sid from oe_exam_result where testid= @testid)) t1
    left join 
        (select  s.testid,(select sid from oe_exam_result where testid=s.testid )as sid,s.correctAns,s.wrongAns,s.sectiontotal from oe_section_wise_result s where testid=@testid) t2
    on
 t1.sid=t2.sid) 
end
```

Comment: Can you post sample SIDs from each select? It sounds like each SID matches all 5 of the other tables results. That is usually how 25 rows result from 5 results in each sub query when joined.

Comment: You said what is returning but never explain what result are you expecting.  We need sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Probably missing alias --> crossjoin. Try add aliases for all of your columns. Select one of your sid into your qry and check which table does multiple rows.